# Jquery check box check

Tags: jquery, angularjs

i have a list of check boxes that generates from a stored procedure and all the selected check boxes are preloaded

that will pre load items that were checked previously and saved to a table like this(it wont let me copy and paste so use your imagination please
check box : true CGM file
checkbox 2 : false file 1
checkbox 3 : true file 2
 my question is how do I go through the loop to see if someone changes the check box value?

Comment: Some code would go a long ways to making this question understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, it's hard to give you a specific answer.  Is this in both jquery and angularjs?  I would probably wrap the jquery plugin inside an angular directive and control it from there with two-way binding (scope: {variable: '='}).  Then set a model for the list of checkboxes.

Comment: <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Select all File Formats to be included</label>
 <div class="col-m-8">                                                                              <label  class="checkbox pull-left col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10" ng-repeat="step in eng_info.build_room_steps">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="step.checked"><small>{{step.FileFormat}}</small>
  </label>
</div>                                                    </div>

Comment: Above is the code that will create the check box list ALL i want is go through that list to see if someone has modified it so i can save it

Comment: All I want to do is go through the list angular created in jquery and find out which values or check boxes got checked. thats all